# C# & Javascript: Help adding javascript to ctrl

Tags: javascript, c#

I think I have this narrowed down to the issue being my JavaScript code. I have this working with an alert but now I want to use my real JavaScript code and its failing. My boss gave me a snippet of some older code that works for a different page/control. So I'm trying to recycle that code and use it here. Anyway I need to do these three things in my JavaScript:

- Password must be at least 8 chars in length
- Password must contain at least one number
- Password must contain at least one capital letter

I have already created a c# version of this function here:

```
bool hasLength= password1.Length > 7;
bool hasDigit = password1.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c));
bool hasCapital = password1.Any(c => char.IsUpper(c));

if(!hasDigit || !hasCapital || !hasLength)
{
    oEr.Number = (int)ErrorClass.ErrorNumber.GeneralError;
    oEr.Message = "Password must be at least 8 characters with at least one number, one capital letter and no symbols.";
}
```

The code above works but its in c# and they want me to write it in JavaScript. Here is what I have currently:

```
string jsPasswordScript = "onchange() " +
            "var pw = document.getElementById('AHA_Password1').value.toString(); "+
            "var passw =/^ (?=.*[0 - 9])(?=.*[a - z])(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.{ 8,})/; "+
            "var res = passw.test(pw); " +
            "if (res) [| label_AHA_Password3.innerText = '';|] "+
            "else "+
            "[|label_AHA_Password3.innerText='Password must be at least 8 characters with at least one number, one capital letter and no symbols.';"+
            " document.getElementById('AHA_Password1').focus();|]];";

oTB.ID = "AHA_Password1";
oTB.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
oTB.TabIndex = 21;
oCell = new HtmlTableCell();
oTB.Attributes.Add("OnChange", jsPasswordScript);
oCell.Controls.Add(oTB);
oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);
```

Currently the JavaScript is not working. It was working when I used an alert just as a test. So something must be wrong with the JavaScript its self. I'm not super good with JavaScript, can anyone see my mistake in JavaScript or suggest a better route ?

**Edit**

I updated my JavaScript code. I'm going to test it but here is what I came up with for my new js code.

```
function passwordvalidation() {
  var password = document.getElementById('password1').value.toString();
  var hasLength = password.length > 7;
  var hasDigit = System.Linq.Enumerable.from(password).any(function(c) {
    return System.Char.isDigit(c);
  });
  var hasCapital = System.Linq.Enumerable.from(password).any(function(c) {
    return Bridge.isUpper(c);
  });

  if (!hasDigit || !hasCapital || !hasLength) {
    label_AHA_Password3.innerText = "Password must be at least 8 characters with at least one number, one capital letter and no symbols.";
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Just kind of a guess here as I don't add Javascript code that way, but since you want to add script to the OnChange event of the control, do you need the first part of your script onChange(), instead of beginning with var pw =

Comment: Also, an if statement in javascript uses curly braces, so I would change this:ShowOfficerDropDowns

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the comment. I agree I don't add my java script this way ether but this is by my bosses request. I adjusted the java script code. Can you outline what your referring to or where you ref the original java script code? I'm not super savvy with java script so I apologize for not understanding your response. Can you post a snippet or example of what your referring too, thanks

Comment: please see the answer below, I believe Racil was kind enough to fix the errors in the script for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are errors in the JavaScript that you're adding to the control:

- You are already adding it to the `OnChange` attribute, so no need for the `onchange()` at the beginning.
- Use curly brackets `{}` for the `if` statement, not square brackets with pipes `[ | | ]`.

Try this:

```
string jsPasswordScript = "var pw = document.getElementById('AHA_Password1').value.toString(); var passw = /^ (?=.*[0 - 9])(?=.*[a - z])(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.{ 8,})/; var res = passw.test(pw); if(res) { label_AHA_Password3.innerText = ''; } else { label_AHA_Password3.innerText = 'Password must be at least 8 characters with at least one number, one capital letter and no symbols.'; document.getElementById('AHA_Password1').focus(); }";
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a answer. It did not work 100% but it did work. I need to do some tweaking. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Ok I think your right 100% i'm a newb lol Thank you very much for helping.